# Update Or Skip Rows with duplicate Primary Key While Bulk Insert - SQL

Tags: sql-server, csv, bulkinsert

I'm using Bulk Insert Method to insert rows from CSV files. But it will fail on duplicate primary keys.

Here is my Sample Code:

```
Use People
Go
BULK
INSERT tblProfile
FROM 'F:\People.txt'
WITH
(
DATAFILETYPE='widechar',
CODEPAGE = 'ACP',
FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
ERRORFILE = 'F:\ErrorRows.csv'
)
GO
```

I need to update fields on duplicate primary keys' rows.

For example here is a sample of my table:

```
Code   Name   Family   City
---------------------------
45     Joe    Stone    USA
67     Sara   Stone    USA
68            Stone
```

if there is a row with code "68" in CSV file and in this row we have name or city (which is empty or null in my table) then bulk insert update and fill them otherwise skip this duplication on primary key and do the insert for others.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to do this?

Answer (score 1):

As DoctorMick stated [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27485083/2118383)

You could set the `MAXERRORS` property to quite a high which will allow the valid records to be inserted and the duplicates to be ignored.  Unfortunately, this will mean that any other errors in the dataset won't cause the load to fail.

Alternatively, you could set the `BATCHSIZE` property which will load the data in multiple transactions therefore if there are duplicates it will only roll back the batch.

Or

Use Temp table to filter the Duplicate and Update it

```
INSERT INTO #tblProfile(Id, Col1) -- temporary table
VALUES 
(3, S3),
(4, S4),
(5, S5)

INSERT INTO tblProfile
SELECT * FROM #tblProfile
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Id FROM #tblProfile WHERE #tblProfile.Id = tblProfile.id)

;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id
                                       ORDER BY ( SELECT 0)) RN
         FROM   #tblProfile)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE  RN > 1

Update T 
SET T.Col1 = ISNULL(T1.Col1,T.Col1)
FROM tblProfile T join #tblProfile T1 ON T.id =T1.id
```

Comment: I saw it, But it does not say how to update duplicate rows if needed!

Comment: If you go for update, you have to insert all data into temp table without primary key and use update from temp table to main table

Comment: How? Could you please show me? I can use C# and SQL Bulk Copy too is needed.

Comment: @Stranger Did u get?

Comment: I can insert all into temp table without primary key, but how yo update from it into main table?

Comment: Yes first insert from temp table to main table without duplicate key by using above mentioned query. After that you can write your own update query to update the records.

Comment: I will try and will back soon ;)